VS code for Python does not show the contents of the variable after the codes are executed
I have a simple Python code written in VS code to print an array:
import numpy as np  # Importing the NumPy library

# Creating a 1D array
array_1d = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
print("1D Array:",array_1d)

The output appears in Python terminal window as follows:

Now I am trying to extract this variable "array_1d" directly in terminal window (IDE shell), but I get an array as such:

How do I get this variable in the IDE shell of VS code?
Note: This problem does not happen with default IDLE shell of Python. How do I see this in VS code.

Lookup jupyter notebook or python shell. This is a terminal (or console). it displays the output of the python script you just ran. It's not a python shell or python interpreter. A python interpreter or jupyter notebooks will let you do that.

Try hitting shift + return after highlighting the code to Run Selection/Line in Python REPL or alternatively use the right click menu:


Python Interpreter and Windows/Linux Shell both use command line environments, but they serve different purposes
The windows/linux shell:

A command-line interface used to run programs, manage computer files and interact with the
computer

The python interpreter:

The interpreter operates somewhat like the Unix shell: when called
with standard input connected to a tty device, it reads and executes
commands interactively; when called with a file name argument or with
a file as standard input, it reads and executes a script from that
file

source: python
I do not know what you are trying to achieve but look up Jupiter notebook you can use it also on vscode follow this link
